# Postman: Bad Request - Expected request content

Tags: python, postman, blacksheep

I'm making REST API with BlackSheep framework, Piccolo ORM and its Pydantic models.

Table in Piccolo ORM:

```
class Expense(Table):
    amount = Integer()
    description = Varchar()
```

Working with Pydantic models in application:

```
from piccolo.utils.pydantic import create_pydantic_model
from blacksheep import Application, FromJSON, json, Response, Content


ExpenseModelIn: typing.Any = create_pydantic_model(table=Expense, model_name="ExpenseModelIn")
ExpenseModelOut: typing.Any = create_pydantic_model(table=Expense, include_default_columns=True, model_name="ExpenseModelOut")


@app.router.post("/expense")
async def create_expense(expense_model: FromJSON[ExpenseModelIn]):
    print(expense_model.value)
    try:
        expense = Expense(**expense_model.value.dict())
        await expense.save()
        return ExpenseModelOut(**expense.to_dict())  
    except:
        return Response(400, content=Content(b"text/plain", b"Bad Request"))
```

When I try to make POST request in Postman I get 400 Bad Request error.
[image: Postman POST request]

If I `print()` content of `ExpenseModelIn` I get `None` for every parameter sent from Postman. Do I need to send parameters in Header section in Postman or where?

P.S. Tried to send in Header section, didn't help.

Comment: Postman is sending form-data but the server appears to expect JSON: `expense_model: FromJSON[ExpenseModelIn]`. Try passing the data in the request body with raw/JSON. It couldn't hurt to ensure the `content-type: application/json` header is set as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data as form-data but trying to get them with FromJSON function from BlackSheep framework.

The solution is to use FromForm instead of FromJSON.

You code should be like:

```
from blacksheep import FromForm

async def create_expense(expense_model: FromForm[ExpenseModelIn]):
    data = expense_model.value
    ...
```

Link to example in official documentation: https://www.neoteroi.dev/blacksheep/requests/#reading-form